# When exporting my video in blender there is this strange secondary text I cannot see in my viewport?

Tags: mesh, extrude, text-object

I am trying to export the video of the text on the (top picture) and it looks normal but when I go to render there is this secondary text (bottom picture) and is in the way of my render as it is covering my main text. I have no clue how to get rid of this! I cannot render my project. I appreciate anyone that helps me.[image: How I see the text before rendering]
[image: Text when in rendering screen]

Answer (score 2):

*Text* and *Text.002* in the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/editors/outliner/introduction.html) are [hidden](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/editors/outliner/interface.html#restriction-columns) in the viewport (eye icon) but not in the render (camera icon). Click the camera icon for both objects and they should be hidden in the render as well.